# If I have a foreign key constraint of a table to itself, do I need to be careful when deleting the whole table?

Tags: sqlite, foreign-keys, referential-integrity

I have a SQLite table that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable (
    _id integer primary key autoincrement,
    ...
    ... /* some useful fields */
    ...
    parent integer,
    FOREIGN KEY (parent) REFERENCES myTable (_id)
);
```

Some of the entries in myTable have a parent, others don't. Business logic ensures that there are no "circles". I'm using `PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON`, so that foreign key violations are detected.

Question: **If I want to delete the whole table, is it enough to execute `DELETE FROM myTable`?** Or do I need to delete the "leaves" first, then their parents, etc., all the way up to avoid foreign key violations?

I've tested it and using just `DELETE FROM myTable` *seems to work*. However, I want to know whether this is just a coincidence or something I can rely upon (i.e. documented and expected behaviour).

---

EDIT: I don't have `ON DELETE CASCADE` enabled, and this is on purpose.

Comment: Bah, I can't get it right! Maybe tonight if it's not already answered.

Answer (score 0):

### Insert

By specifying a [foreign key](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html) and with `PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON`, starting from an empty table, SQLite will deny you any entry of data (except identities, where `parent = _id`) with the message:

> Error: foreign key constraint failed.

So from the start, you need to make at least one entry with `PRAGMA foreign_keys = OFF` or a "circular" entry.

### Deletion of specific entries

If you do not provide an [action](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_actions) such as `CASCADE` to your [foreign key](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html), SQLite will deny deletion of a "parent entry" if the parent has children due to the foreign key constraint. This is the default behaviour, equivalent to "NO ACTION".

### Deletion of all entries

Deletion of all entries is possible through `DELETE FROM myTable` and should not trigger the foreign key constraints on the same table, even if there is no cascade clause. I verified by test, it might not be documented.

Comment: Re your first point: Since `parent` is nullable, adding new rows with `parent = NULL` is possible even if `PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON`. Re deletion: Thanks for testing it; I'll leave the question open in case anyone finds this documented anywere (which is what I'm looking for).